# How to create instance of class TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have the following class:

```
export declare class FlashMessagesService {
    show: (text?: string, options?: Object) => void;
    grayOut: (value: boolean) => void;
}
```

And I try to create instance of class:

```
 import { FlashMessagesService } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
    let _flashMessagesService = new FlashMessagesService();
```

It invoke an error:

```
Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

I use this [library](https://github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages)

Comment: I think we need to see the `show` method or how it's invoked

Comment: ... btw I don't think you need the `declare` keyword - I think that is generally only for ambient context. i.e. it doesn't emit javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you problem is typescript per se, but with angular dependency injection and how components are composed instead.

If you look at the source code of the package you are using you will see that `show` function is actually implemented by the [FlashMessagesComponent](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages@f6ab664df6982bec4200ab18d38c1198651a8678/-/blob/module/flash-messages.component.ts#L29) and [not by FlashMessagesService itself](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages@f6ab664df6982bec4200ab18d38c1198651a8678/-/blob/module/flash-messages.service.ts#L6).

So to create an instance of it on your own without angular's dependency injection it is going to be tricky because you would also need to provide an instance of the abstract class `ChangeDetectorRef`, which itself might depend on other stuff, so it might get really messy pretty quickly.

something like the code bellow might help you to start playing with it, but it is far from something you would want to use in the real world.

```
import { FlashMessagesService, FlashMessagesComponent } from 'angular2-flash-messages';
let _flashMessagesService = new FlashMessagesService();
let component = new FlashMessagesComponent(_flashMessagesService, { detectChanges: () => {}} );
console.log(_flashMessagesService.show) // [Function show]
```

---

EDIT:

I coded directly here on SO and could not test it (sorry :( ), now checking it more thoroughly it seems that [FlashMessagesComponent it not exported](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages@f6ab664df6982bec4200ab18d38c1198651a8678/-/blob/module/index.ts), so I don't clearly see a way for you to create an instance without using `FlashMessagesModule` and angular dependency injection lifecycle.

Comment: I can not find `FlashMessagesComponent`

Comment: What is it? ` { detectChanges: () => {}} ;`?

Comment: _I can not find FlashMessagesComponent_ - sorry, I just checked and ]it is not exported](https://sourcegraph.com/github.com/moff/angular2-flash-messages@f6ab664df6982bec4200ab18d38c1198651a8678/-/blob/module/index.ts)  

Comment: `{ detectChanges: () => {}} ;` it is just a hack to avoid having to create an instance of whatever class is `ChangeDetectorRef` that is a dependency on the constructor.

Comment: It is des not work for me, I put null and it gives me `core.es5.js:1020 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'detectChanges' of null`

Comment: it sholud be obect as `ChangeDetectorRef`;

Comment: `es5` hmmm so `() => {}` is a no go as it is a `es6` feature, replace it by `{ detectChanges: function() { } }` instead

Comment: *I don't clearly see a way for you to create an instance without using FlashMessagesModule* - so you likely shouldn't. The OP clearly has XY problem. and the way the question was stated doesn't allow to provide a quality answer. `detectChanges` is a hack that shouldn't be used without a very good reason, and none was provided so far.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a constructor for your class before :

```
export class Flashmessages { 
    ...
    //other vars
    constructor(){
        this.myvar = "value";
    }
}
```

Comment: Where? And what should be in construct?

Comment: I wouldn't expect lack of constructor to cause this error

Comment: I think is is declaration(interface): `export declare class FlashMessagesService {}`